# Why do I get duplicate Kerberos service tickets with no realm?

Tags: ssh, macports, kerberos

Under what circumstances will I obtain apparently-valid service tickets that are duplicates *and* that don't have an associated realm? That is, does this indicate a mis-configuration somewhere? Does it represent an interesting capability or opportunity? ... an inefficiency or a vulnerability?

For example, if I `kinit` successfully to obtain my TGT, SSH to a kerberized host, then run `klist`, I see this (sanitized) output:

```
Ticket cache: KCM:503
Default principal: neirbowj@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
01/24/2016 18:17:40  01/25/2016 04:17:40  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
    renew until 01/25/2016 18:17:33
01/24/2016 18:17:45  01/25/2016 04:17:40  host/foo.example.com@
    renew until 01/25/2016 18:17:33
01/24/2016 18:17:45  01/25/2016 04:17:40  host/foo.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
    renew until 01/25/2016 18:17:33
```

What does it mean that I have both `host/foo.example.com@` and `host/foo.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM` service tickets?

I'm running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 and using the kerberos5 1.13.2_2 port and the openssh 7.1p2_0+kerberos5+ldns+xauth port from MacPorts 2.3.4. My (sanitized) `/etc/krb5.conf` has:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
[realms]
    EXAMPLE.COM = {
        admin_server = kerberos.example.com
    }
```